# "index.week" filter when using iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a condition my basic script to only look for `if row['Val'] > 1.5:`if the current week has not already matched a value.  So with my script I currently get this (with two entries on week 7 and 8):

```
Week is: 3.0 
Value is: 2.55241826585
Week is: 6.0 
Value is: 1.55068781498
Week is: 7.0 
Value is: 1.50624949327
Week is: 7.0 
Value is: 1.64751555163
Week is: 8.0 
Value is: 1.79860293902
Week is: 8.0 
Value is: 1.97472511905
Week is: 9.0 
Value is: 2.31025762754
Week is: 10.0
```

Desired output is this:

```
Week is: 3.0 
Value is: 2.55241826585
Week is: 6.0 
Value is: 1.55068781498
Week is: 7.0 
Value is: 1.64751555163
Week is: 8.0 
Value is: 1.79860293902
Week is: 9.0 
Value is: 2.31025762754
Week is: 10.0
```

So week 7 and 8 only have one entry.

Pseudo code:

if no other match this week:
   do stuff

**Data:**

```
ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts.columns = ['Val']
ts['Week'] = ts.index.week
for index, row in ts.iterrows():
    if row['Val'] > 1.5:
        print("Week is:",row['Week'],'\n'"Value is:",row['Val'])
```

Comment: why not `drop_duplicates(subset='Week')` prior to iteration?

Comment: See [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) : `ts = ts.drop_duplicates(subset='Week')`

Comment: Hi EdChum, always really appreciate your input you have helped me a lot.  This is a simple dummy example and I appreciate your suggestion is a better way to do this but I also need to learn how to do the iterrows option for when I am using lots of conditions and using .shift etc on complex dataset (market data).

Comment: You'd need to store the previous week value and compare with current row week and skip if it matches but to me this is wholly unnecessary

Comment: This post is just for me to learn how to do this when iterating.  My actual dataset has lots of conditions and is not so simple.  I provided a dummy sample as Im always told to do so.   Even Wes McKinney says "I agree vectorization is the right solution where possible-- sometimes an iterative algorithm is the only way though."

Comment: Thanks again EdChum.  Always learning from you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter beforehand instead of iterating on each row, and then can drop the duplicates. Here's a one-liner using [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), row by row:

```
 ts[ts.Val>1.5].drop_duplicates(subset='Week').apply(lambda row: 
                                                print("Week is:",row['Week'],
                                                      '\n'"Value is:",row['Val']),
                                                axis=1)
```

---

If you really want to blindly iterate on each row, so be it. Just use a list to store the weeks, and check if they aren't already done...

```
ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts.columns = ['Val']
ts['Week'] = ts.index.week
weeks_done = []
for index, row in ts.iterrows():
    if (row['Val'] > 1.5) & (row['Week'] not in weeks_done):
        print("Week is:",row['Week'],'\n'"Value is:",row['Val'])
        weeks_done.append(row['Week'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this post is just for me to learn how to do this when iterating as per request "I would like to add a condition my basic script '. My actual dataset has lots of conditions and is not so simple. I provided a dummy sample as Im always told to do so

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience.